# Matching images

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa

I`ve got a very unexpected problem which making me crazy. This is very simple type of memory game with 36 cards. In code below I making array with 36 objets (18 double objects). Everything works great when you choose card between 1-12. When you choose higher card, matching process can't recognize match. Why???

memory.m

```
for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; ++i)
{
    int n = i;
    [imagesArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    NSLog(@"index obrázku %i",i);
    NSLog(@"index array %i",n);
}

// Set button images
for (int i=0; i<[buttonsArray count]; i++) {
NSLog(@"index button %i",i);

UIButton *singleButton = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i];    
[singleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:TILE_BACKGROUND] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[singleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:TILE_BACKGROUND] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

if ([[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] == 1) {
    [singleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:TILE_IMAGE1] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    NSLog(@"Karta 1 tag %i",i);
} else if ([[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] == 2) {
    [singleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:TILE_IMAGE2] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    NSLog(@"Karta 2 tag %i",i);
}
```

objects are from 1 to 18...

```
- (IBAction)tileClicked:(id)sender {

    // Button is clicked
    if (!matchingInPogress) {
        UIButton *clickedButton = sender;
        tilesOpened++;
        NSLog(@"Počet otočených karet je %i",tilesOpened);
        [clickedButton setEnabled:NO];

        if (tilesOpened == 1) {
            // Only one tiled opened, remeber tag for match
            openTileIndex = clickedButton.tag;
        } else {
            // Second tile is opened, perform match
            matchingInPogress = YES;
            [self performSelector:@selector(matchTiles:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:clickedButton.tag] afterDelay:0.5];
            tilesOpened = 0;
        }
    }
```

button control..

```
- (void)matchTiles:(NSNumber *)clickedTile {

    // Match opened tiles
    int clickedTileIndex = [clickedTile integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Karta 1 tag %i",clickedTileIndex);
    NSLog(@"Karta 2 tag %i",openTileIndex);

    if ([imagesArray objectAtIndex:clickedTileIndex] != [imagesArray objectAtIndex:openTileIndex]) {
        NSLog(@"Porovnává hodnoty v clickedTileIndex a openTileIndex");

        // If tiles don't match set them to enabled state
        UIButton *firstButton = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:openTileIndex];
        UIButton *secondButton = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:clickedTileIndex];
        NSLog(@"Nesouhlas tag je %i",openTileIndex);
        NSLog(@"Nesouhlas tag je %i",clickedTileIndex);

        [firstButton setEnabled:YES];
        [secondButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Match!");
        UIButton *firstButton = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:openTileIndex];
        UIButton *secondButton = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:clickedTileIndex];
        NSLog(@"Souhlas tag je %i",openTileIndex);
        NSLog(@"Souhlas tag je %i",clickedTileIndex);
        [firstButton setHidden:YES];
        [secondButton setHidden:YES];
    }

    matchingInPogress = NO;
}
```

and finaly matching process

Thanks!

Comment: @Juhana: I guess Obj-C / Cocoa... I am setting the tags accordingly

Comment: There is a distinct lack of information here imo

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays can only contain objects, you don't test them with `!=` as that will only compare the value of the pointers and not the objects themselves.  Very often, this works (even though you wouldn't expect it to) for some (usually low) values but quits working on others because UIKit objects often cache objects sand return the same object address, even for different instances.

You need to change this line in tileClicked:

```
if ([imagesArray objectAtIndex:clickedTileIndex] != [imagesArray objectAtIndex:openTileIndex]) {
```

to this:

```
if (![(UIImage *)[imagesArray objectAtIndex:clickedTileIndex] isEqual:
     (UIImage *)[imagesArray objectAtIndex:openTileIndex]]) {
```